# fprintf valgrind error

Tags: c, printf, valgrind

My program sorts the input from a text file and then `fprintf` it into output file. However valgrind reports some nasty errors for `fprintf` calls, which I do not understand. Any hints whats the reason for them?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void * mymalloc (int size)
{
static int count=0;
if (count<100)
{
    count++;
    return malloc(size);
}
else return NULL;
}
char* getline(FILE * infile)
{
int size = 16;
char * line = (char*)mymalloc(size);
int temp;

int i=0;
do
{
    (temp = fgetc(infile));
    if (temp !=EOF)
        line[i++]=(char)temp;
    if (i>=size)    
    {
        size*=2;
        line = (char*)realloc(line, size);
    }

}while (temp != '\n' && temp !=EOF);
line[i+1]='\0';
if (temp==EOF)
    {
        free(line);
        return NULL;
    }
return line;
}
void print_line (char * line)
{
printf("%s ", line);
}

int myCompare (const void * a, const void * b )
{
const char *pa = *(const char**)a;
const char *pb = *(const char**)b;

return strcmp(pa,pb);
}
     int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
FILE * infile;
FILE * outfile;

infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (infile==NULL)
{
    printf("Error");
    exit(3);
}
outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
if (outfile==NULL)
{
    printf("Error");
    exit(3);
}
char * line;
char **all_lines;
int nlines=0;

while((line=getline(infile))!=NULL)
{
    print_line(line);
    nlines++;
    free(line);
}

all_lines=mymalloc(nlines*sizeof(char*));
rewind(infile);
int j=0;
printf("%d\n\n", nlines);

while((line=getline(infile))!=NULL)
{

    all_lines[j]=line;
    j++;
}

qsort(all_lines, nlines, sizeof(char*), myCompare);

for (int i=0; i<nlines;i++)
{
    //print_line(all_lines[i]);
    fprintf(outfile, "%s " , all_lines[i]);
}

for(int i =0; i<nlines;i++)
{
    free(all_lines[i]);
}

free(all_lines);
fclose(infile);
fclose(outfile);
return 0;   
}
```

Valgrind errors :

```
==3678== 11 errors in context 1 of 2:
==3678== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3678==    at 0x40BA4B1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1601)
==3678==    by 0x40C0F3E: fprintf (fprintf.c:33)
==3678==    by 0x8048964: main (sort_lines.c:99)
==3678==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==3678==    at 0x4024C1C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==3678==    by 0x80486FB: mymalloc (sort_lines.c:11)
==3678==    by 0x804871C: getline (sort_lines.c:18)
==3678==    by 0x8048905: main (sort_lines.c:87)
==3678== 
==3678== 
==3678== 11 errors in context 2 of 2:
==3678== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3678==    at 0x40BA4B1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1601)
==3678==    by 0x40C0F7F: printf (printf.c:35)
==3678==    by 0x80487B8: print_line (sort_lines.c:44)
==3678==    by 0x804887D: main (sort_lines.c:77)
==3678==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==3678==    at 0x4024D12: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:476)
==3678==    by 0x8048766: getline (sort_lines.c:30)
==3678==    by 0x804889A: main (sort_lines.c:75)
==3678== 
--3678-- 
--3678-- used_suppression:     17 dl-hack3-cond-1
==3678== 
==3678== ERROR SUMMARY: 22 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 8)
```

Comment: Might help to tell us what those nasty errors are exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1 uninitiliazed character before '\0' character ending the string (each time you are adding character you post increment the `i` counter so there is no need to add `i+1` when adding `'\0'`. Replace `line[i+1]='\0';` with `line[i]='\0';`:

```
char* getline(FILE * infile)
{
int size = 16;
char * line = (char*)mymalloc(size);
int temp;

int i=0;
do
{
    (temp = fgetc(infile));
    if (temp !=EOF)
        line[i++]=(char)temp;
    if (i>=size)
    {
        size*=2;
        line = (char*)realloc(line, size);
    }

}while (temp != '\n' && temp !=EOF);
line[i]='\0'; //// <- change here
if (temp==EOF)
    {
        free(line);
        return NULL;
    }
return line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While trying to compile your program using gcc version 4.3.4 in SUSE linux, i am seeing the below compilation errors.

Your getline function is conflicting with the getline function in  header file.This is not a solution to your problem but i feel its better to use some other function name in place of  getline.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

```
user/home> gcc -g so1.c
so1.c:16: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
/usr/include/stdio.h:653: error: previous declaration of 'getline' was here
so1.c: In function 'main':
so1.c:98: error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
so1.c:104: error: redefinition of 'i'
so1.c:98: error: previous definition of 'i' was here
so1.c:104: error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
```